# SpringData Neo4J: relationship between @NodeEntity and raw Neo4J entity

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

Is it possible to create a relationship between a Spring Data Neo4J @NodeEntity and a raw Neo4J node (`org.neo4j.graphdb.Node`)?  If so, how is this done and how is this referred to within SDN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do it using Neo4jTemplate:

1. Convert entity to Node:

   Node firstNode = (Node)neo4jTemplate.getPersistentState(entity);
2. Create relationship, using the node you had and the node you converted:

   neo4jTemplate.createRelationshipBetween(firstNode, secondNode, relType, params);

The second option is to find entity using data from node and create relationship using entities.

Comment: Thanks very much - in your second option, what happens if the node was not created in Spring Data Neo4J (i.e. it doesn't have an SDN entity)?  In this situation, there is one node and one entity - is it possible to bring the node into SDN, rather than the SDN entity into raw Neo4J as a node?

Comment: Well, if you use Neo4jTemplate class or your own GraphRepository to find an entity (using the data from node as a way to identify that entity) the fetched entity will be managed. I assume the node represents existing node in graph database and it has all metadata required by SDN (usually it is additional label with underscore). To be honest, I don't quite understand why you insist on mixing those concepts - if I were you I would try stick to one method of access and try not to mix them if not really necessary...

Comment: Thanks - mixing the elements isn't my choice, it's because a separate library (GraphAware TimeTree) uses raw N4J and I want to use SDN.

Comment: Ok, now I understand. :) Than just investigate the results of that library actions to see if you do not miss any metadata SDN needs.